# How to reference external JPA/JAXB domain model project?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa, jaxb, glassfish

I am developing a client/server application currently, where the server consists of a RESTful interface (jersey) and the client is a JSF application. Both are running on a glassfish 3.1.1 server. To persist some data and produce XML output I created a domain model with JAXB and JPA (eclipselink) annotations. Everything is fine, as long as the domain classes are within the server project.
But I want to define the domain model in an external project, so that it can be used by the client (xml -> object) and the REST server (object -> xml) by referencing its *.jar.
I alread achieved, that the JPA works correctly on the server, but the JAXB functionality has been "removed".

I am very new to the Java EE stack.. maybe I am packaging in a wrong way. Would be very happy, if someone could give me a hint :-)

Comment: What do you mean by the JAXB functionality has been removed?

Comment: That means that the automatic transformation into XML did not work anymore. When I returned an object in a jersey-method, it got converted to a simple string, not to XML... nevertheless persisting the object worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it worked after setting the following project facets:

- Java
- JAXB
- JPA
- Uitility Module

After that: adding to build path and setting a project reference...